# How do I find records in one table that do exist in another but based on a date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find all the dealers who haven't had an order in 2015 yet.  I know this query doesn't work but I thought it might be helpful to understand what I want to do.  In this example I want to get just "Bob" as a result.  He is the only dealer in this example to not have an order in 2015 yet.

```
SELECT d.`name` 
FROM z_dealer d 
LEFT JOIN z_order o ON (d.promo_code = o.promo_code) 
WHERE o.promo_code IS NULL
AND o.date_ordered > '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Here is the table data...

```
mysql> Select * from z_order;
+----+-------+------------+---------------------+
| id | total | promo_code | date_ordered        |
+----+-------+------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 10    | holiday    | 2014-06-22 09:06:50 |
| 2  | 20    | special    | 2015-06-22 09:07:04 |
| 3  | 15    | holiday    | 2015-03-01 09:07:23 |
| 4  | 45    | special    | 2014-09-03 09:07:33 |
| 5  | 16    | laborday   | 2014-06-22 09:09:01 |
+----+-------+------------+---------------------+



mysql> select * from z_dealer;
+----+------+------------+
| id | name | promo_code |
+----+------+------------+
| 1  | John | holiday    |
| 2  | Suzy | special    |
| 3  | Bob  | laborday   |
+----+------+------------+
```

Comment: should that read WHERE o.promo_code IS NOT NULL

Comment: The part `o.promo_code IS NULL` should probably be taken out or be put into a subquery.  Because there is a record that does exist with that join, but when you apply the date it shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select d.`name`
from z_dealer d
where
  (select count(*)
   from z_order o
   WHERE o.promo_code = d.promo_code
   AND o.date_ordered > '2015-01-01') = 0
```

Comment: Hmm...I don't get any results when I run that.

Comment: Does my edited version  work - wasn't thinking as I did a cut & paste

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the query that you want to compare timestamps, not strings, and you need to include all the JOIN conditions in the ON clause of the JOIN, not in the WHERE clause. Change the query to

```
SELECT d.`name` 
  FROM Table2 d 
  LEFT JOIN Table1 o ON (d.promo_code = o.promo_code AND
                         o.date_ordered > TIMESTAMP '2015-01-01 00:00:00') 
  WHERE o.promo_code IS NULL
```

Best of luck.

Comment: showing syntax error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2015-01-01 00:00:00'' at line 5`  SQLFIDDLE=http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d15e/10

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT d.`name` 
    FROM z_dealer d 
    LEFT JOIN z_order o ON (d.promo_code = o.promo_code) 
    WHERE o.promo_code IS NULL
    AND o.date_ordered > 2015-01-01 00:00:00
```

Date value between ' ' is read as a string value not a DateTime. So above code works. And if you want your result "Bob" remove Where clause from query as it is considered as predicate which may alter your results.

P.S you should not use hyphens in Date Value as its representing cultural format. Have a look at [This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191307.aspx)  for good practices.

Comment: That is giving me an error.  I guess I should note that I am using MySQL in my example.

Comment: did you try replacing d.'name' to d.name ?

Comment: MySQL accepts dates as strings, also defaults time to 00:00:00 if omitted, see my answer above (which, hopefully Chad will mark as correct, after commenting it works ;-) )

Comment: I just tried that and still get the same error. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00' at line 5`